# ¿Cómo utilizar images descargadas de servidor en Android?

Tags: android, imagen, servidor

Mi problema es el siguiente: Cada imagen en mi carpeta *Drawable* en *Android* están codificadas. Ejemplo: **2010i20** (año + número romano + número") luego obtengo el *id* de cada imagen y lo muestro en un `ImageView`, pero el problema es que ya tengo demasiadas imágenes y hacen muy pesado el *apk*.

Quisiera poder descargar esas imágenes desde un servidor pero solo una vez y guardarlas en una carpeta dentro de la aplicación (**data/data** - pero no necesariamente esta carpeta), que no se muestre en la galería de *Android*, y a la vez como puedo obtener una referencia a esa imagen para poder mostrarla en un `ImageView`

Comment: Puedes intentar con está librería [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/). Te permite tanto descargar como guardar en cache las imagenes de tu app.

Comment: ¿Crear una carpeta llamada `.<miapp>` y tomar las imagenes de ahí, no funciona?

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español. Por favor toma el **[recorrido del sitio](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)** y lee 
**[cómo crear una buena pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)**. Estás ahciendo 2 preguntas: `¿descargar y guardar imágenes en una carpeta de tu aplicación?` y `obtener referencia de la imagen para mostrarla`. **[edit] tu  pregunta** con lo que hayas intentado (código, etc).